# How to get more results in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

I am searching for certain type of businesses in Google Maps and I am gathering data for a directory database. I have created a layer and add markers from each city I am searching into.

Always, when I type "indian restaurants New York City" or "parking lots Rome" it fetches 10 results (not sure about Google Maps order). It appears that there are thousands, but only 10 results are being fetched. Some times, I saw a bit more (11 or 12) but I don't know why.

Is there any way I could fetch more results? I don't have a problem to get them 10 at a time, but I just can't get the next ones.